# Copy to clipboard value of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to copy to clipboard a value of selected option from `select` list using jQuery or JavaScript.

My html:

```
<select id="choose-color">
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="green">GREEN</option>
    <option value="yellow">YELLOW</option>
    <option value="black">BLACK</option>
</select>
```

The value should be copied to clipboard when the user choose any option. I tried to use `clipboard.js` plugin but it seems not working with select list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `input` to make copy to clipboard. I have create an `input` on the change event and removed it after copying the value into clipboard.

Basically you need two function for copy to clipboard .i.e [`select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) and [`execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). The [`select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) method is used to select the contents of a text field. And [`execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) method executes the specified command for the selected part of an editable section.

Here is an working example.

```js
$('#choose-color').on('change', function(){
  var value= `<input value="${$(this).val()}" id="selVal" />`;
  $(value).insertAfter('#choose-color');
  $("#selVal").select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  $('body').find("#selVal").remove();
});
```

```css
black
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choose-color">
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="green">GREEN</option>
    <option value="yellow">YELLOW</option>
    <option value="black">BLACK</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari (I'm using 17.0)

Comment: @martin execCommand is deprecated, instead use `navigator.clipboard.writeText("a sample text!");`

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari. My related question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351436/writing-to-the-clipboard-onchange-of-a-dropdown-element-in-safari

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a temporary element say `textarea` to set the value of the `select` and use that to copy the value. After it has been copied to clipboard remove that `textarea` element.

```js
$('#choose-color').change(function(){
  var textarea = $('<textarea />');
  textarea.val($(this).val()).css({
    visibility: 'none'
  }).appendTo('body');
  textarea.focus().select();
   if (document.execCommand('copy')) {
      textarea.remove();
      return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choose-color">
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="green">GREEN</option>
    <option value="yellow">YELLOW</option>
    <option value="black">BLACK</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can u help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374846/copy-to-clipboard-from-two-html-elements

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari 17.0

Answer (score 0):

Using the `copy()` function in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46215202/9776732) great answer you can easily do the copy to clipboard for dropdown also,

```
document.getElementById('choose-color').onclick = function () {
    let text = this.value;
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', text);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    var result = document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input)
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.execCommand('copy')` to do that.

https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f