# Writing to the clipboard onChange of a dropdown element in Safari

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write text to the clipboard when a user selects an option from a dropdown menu. The following works for all browsers except Safari:

```
<select onChange="writeTextToClipboard(this.value);">
  <option value="Text I want to copy">Copy to clipboard</option>
</select>

function writeTextToClipboard(value) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(value);
}
```

I understand that Safari expects a Promise to be passed to the `write` function of the clipboard object, so following [this blog post](https://wolfgangrittner.dev/how-to-use-clipboard-api-in-firefox/), I modified my code:

```
async function writeTextToClipboard(value) {
  // Safari, Chrome
  if(typeof ClipboardItem && navigator.clipboard.write) {
    const type = 'text/plain'
    const blob = new Blob([value], {type})
    const cbi = new ClipboardItem({[type]: blob})
    await navigator.clipboard.write([cbi])
    console.log(`Copied: ${value}`)
  }
  // Firefox
  else {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(value);
  }
}
```

This still throws a `NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.` on Safari <s>and also breaks on Chrome with `NotAllowedError: Invalid Blob types.`</s> Am I missing something?

I'm on Safari 17.0

**UPDATES**:

- I fixed the issue on Chrome, but it still doesn't work on Safari. I've created a [fiddle with a minimal example](https://jsfiddle.net/martinschneider23/hb9sxk4e/3/).
- I also realized that my example works when it's called in the `onClick` handler of a button instead of `onChange` of a select element. I clarified my use-case.
- The only solution I can think of at the moment is to re-build the dropdown menu with something other than a `select` element and use the `onClick` event handler on that, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.
- This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941892/copy-to-clipboard-value-of-selected-option), but the solutions mentioned in that post are using `execCommand()` which is deprecated and doesn't work either.

Comment: What I am thankful for :) I don’t want to make Code from the internet writing something to my clipboard

Comment: Might be some permissions missing on your mac or browser?

Comment: @Thallius That's debatable. If it's triggered by an explicit user action (for instance, a button saying "Please copy this information to my clipboard") it's ok and useful. It's used widely all over the internet.

There's an API for it that Safari supposedly implements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Comment: I believe your `writeTextToClipboard` function has to be triggered by a user action, like a button click.  Is it?  Or are you just calling it in an unsolicited way (e.g. on page load)

Comment: I call this in the onchange event of a dropdown like this: `<select onChange="somemethod()">`. The `somemethod` function calls `writeTextToClipboard` which is async.

Comment: I've created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/martinschneider23/hb9sxk4e/3/. This works on Firefox and Chrome but fails on Safari.

Comment: See [Features gated by user activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation) for details about how this security mechanism works. The dispatching of a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event alone is not enough to grant the needed permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get it to work in Safari, it needs to be a two-step procedure:

1. Store the value from the `<select>` in a hidden `<input>`
2. Copy the value from the `<input>` to clipboard via a `<button>`:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')

function store(value) {
  input.value = value
}

async function copy() {
  await navigator.clipboard.writeText(input.value)
  console.log(`Copied: ${input.value}`)
}
```

```html
<select onchange="store(this.value)">
  <option value="">--Select your text--</option>
  <option value="Text 1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="Text 2">Text 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" hidden/>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
```

This should work in all browsers. If your design currently does have room for an extra button, make room for it. There's no way around this.

Comment: This works on Chrome, but still fails on Safari.

Comment: I tried both passing a string to the Blob and reading from a DOM element like in your example. Safari still throws the same `NotAllowedError`.

Comment: Fiddle to reproduce is here: https://jsfiddle.net/martinschneider23/hb9sxk4e/3/

Comment: @martin My code works. You need use a `<button>` for the action, not a `<select>` used in your fiddle.

Comment: It works indeed. It seems onclick is considered a user triggered event, but onchange is not. Not sure if this can be modified to support my use-case because I'm stuck with the dropdown for the UI, it can't easily be changed to a button (there are multiple options to select, not just one)

Comment: @martin In that case, consider using a dummy `<input>` for holding the `<select>` value and then copy to clipboard from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941892/copy-to-clipboard-value-of-selected-option

Comment: I've tried something similar before, but, sadly, none of the solutions in the link you shared work on Safari (they only work in other browsers)

Comment: @martin It needs to be a two-step procedure for Safari to work. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is one gotcha with permissions that had me scratching my head some time ago when I was trying the same...in Safari the webpage has to be served over **https**! Won't do nothing over plain old "http" or launching a local html file://

The following definitely works in Safari for simple text copy (over https) and as you've said it has to be a promise.

```
 navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() {

        //do something here if you want, like inform the user that some text has been copied to clipboard

  }, function(err) {

        console.log('Could not copy to clipboard');

 });
```

Comment: Wouldn't jsfiddle qualify as it's served over https?

Comment: I've tried your exact code on my webpage: https://baiyue.5164.at. You can click on one of the map markers. In the pop-up there's a "Navigation" dropdown. "Copy location" calls the function in question. This works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari (I log the error to the console)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way getting this to work with Safari because the `onChange` event of a dropdown is not an [activation triggering input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation).

Following [this answer](https://#answer-77359146), I've added a fallback mechanism that displays a dialog (using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)) with a button to confirm copying the text to the clipboard.

```
function writeTextToClipboard(value) {
  writeTextToClipboard(value, false);
}

function writeTextToClipboard(value, isFallback) {
  // Safari, Chrome, Edge
  if(typeof ClipboardItem && navigator.clipboard.write) {
    const type = 'text/plain'
    const blob = new Blob([value], {type})
    const cbi = new ClipboardItem({[type]: blob})
    navigator.clipboard.write([cbi]).then(function() {
    }, function(err) {
      // For security reasons, modifying the clipboard on the onChange event of
      // a dropdown (select) won't work in Safari (as of 2023) because it's not
      // an "activation triggering input event", see
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation.
      //
      // As a fallback, we display a dialog and use the onClick event of the
      // 'Copy' button to write to the clipboard. See also:
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351436/writing-to-the-clipboard-onchange-of-a-dropdown-element-in-safari/77356042
      if (!isFallback) {
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Copy to clipboard",
          text: value,
          confirmButtonText: "Copy"
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            writeTextToClipboard(value, true);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  // Firefox
  else {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(value);
  }
}
```